# Formulario de busqueda avanzada

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario de búsqueda avanzada con `input` y `checkbox`, en el cual se puede ingresar el nombre o seleccionar uno o todos los checkbox pero ¿cómo puedo hacerlo para que tome los valores ingresados para realizar la busqueda en `mysql`?.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="datos_cotizacion">

    <div class="form-group row">

        <label for="q" class="col-md-2 control-label">Nombres:</label>

        <div class="col-md-5">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="q" placeholder="Nombre">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="pais" value="chile"> Chile</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="viajes"> <label for="cbox2">Viajes</label>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ></span> Buscar</button>
            <span id="loader"></span>

        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Hay montones de ejemplos (incluso en este mismo sitio) sobre como hacer una consulta mysql desde php. ¿Podrías ser más específico sobre el problema que tienes?

Comment: Podías colocar la parte de `php` donde haces la consulta SQL, y ademas si concretas el error que tienes, sería mejor para ayudare y no ser tan genericos